# What MIME type is the tuple type passing to its elements to display them?

Tags: julia

If I implement

```
show(::IO, MIME"text/plain", m::MyType)
```

then this is called by Arrays but not by Tuples. What MIME type are tuples passing to MyType?

Comment: Not sure if this is the officially sanctioned method, but I got good result from redefining: `show(::IOContext, m::MyType)`